# Meaning of the term $X/H$ and orbits

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, definition, group-actions

I am trying to find representations of the group $G=GL_2(F(t)/t^2) = (M_2(F_p) , + ) \rtimes GL_n(F)$
So I was trying to do exactly what Serre has explained in this section.

I am not quite able to understand what does the following sentence mean 
 ' systems of representativesfor the orbits of $H$ in $X$ '

ALso here what is denoted by $X/H$ ? does it correspond to quotient group ? 
If it is a group action then what is the action ?

I am confused.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: $X/H$ is the set of orbit for the $H$-action on $X$. A system of representatives consists of picking one element per orbit.

Comment: So now my first step should be to find orbits for $H$ actions on $X$ right ? after I finish the $G$ actions on $X$